# ImageMagick Warning (TIF Conversion)

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

When I convert a Multi-Image TIF File to Individual TIF Files using ImageMagick I'm getting a Warning stating "Invalid TIFF Directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order'.

```
convert.exe: Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. 
'TIFFReadDirectoryCheckorder' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/847
```

Hoping for Any advice I can get on this error.  I am trying to take a Multi-Image TIF File and Turn it into Individual Files, however I need them to be in the order in which they were listed in the Original TIF File for this to work.

Comment: A few questions: 1) what version of ImageMagick are you using? 2) What is your platform/Operating system? 3) Can you provide a sample tiff file?

Comment: The warning message from ImageMagick is very clear and also non-fatal. It has nothing to do with what you're trying to do, but with the software that created the multi-page files.

Comment: You can suppress nonfatal warnings by adding -quiet to your command line before reading the input image. `convert -quiet ...`

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the issue check the limitation disk:
`convert -list resource`

Example for debian 9 `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`.

I hope that could be helpful.

Comment: I think you are on the wrong track with this answer. The issue is unlikely to be a lack of resources.